# require is not a function/ need hellp

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require('express') ;
const router = require('express-promise-router');

const {validateBody , schemas} = require=('../helpers/routeHelper');


const usersController = require('../controlles/users');

router.route('/signup')
    .post(validateBody(schemas.authSchema),usersController.signUp);

router.route('/signin')
    .post(usersController.signIn);

router.route('/secret')
    .get(usersController.secret);


module.exports= router;
```

Comment: Check your code carefully, please. The third row contains unnecessary `=` in `require=('..`

Comment: Hi. could you elaborate a little bit more your question. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `require=('../helpers/routeHelper');` is not correct.  It should be `require('../helpers/routeHelper');`

Answer (score 0):

This line of code has an extra `=` in it:

```
require=('../helpers/routeHelper'); 
       ^
```

and should be:

```
require('../helpers/routeHelper');
```